# Parsing a .TSV file and write the data into a new .TSV file by re arranging the columns

Tags: python, file

So, I want to read a TSV file (>1M rows) and open another tsv file which will copy the exact data but re-arrange the columns.

For example,

Original tsv file:

```
A   B . . . . .H
a1  b1.. . . . h1
a2  b2. . . . .h2
a3  b3. . . . .h3
.   .. . . . . . so on.
```

(The first line are the headers)

I know how to create, read and write a file but I don't know how to re-arrange the columns.

```
file_location = 'abc.tsv'
output_filename = 'sample.tsv'


def main():
    file_reader = open(file_location,'r')
    new_file = open(output_filename,'w')

    for rows in file_reader:
        try:
                rows = rows.strip().split('\t')


        except Exception, e:
            print('Error in reading file: %s' % e)
            pass

    file_reader.close()
    new_file.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Expected output :

```
D   G . . . . B
d1  g1. . . . b1
d2  g2. . . . b2
d3  g3. . . . b3
d4  g4. . . . b4
.   . . . . . .
.  .  . . . . . so on.
```

Any ideas are appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Python's built-in `csv` module can handle tsv files so I suggest you use it — just specify `delmiter='\t'` when creating a reader or writer.

Comment: My problem is re arranging the columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, you could use the `csv` module to do this. It would also be fairly fast (notice there's no explicit loop over the rows or fields of the files, plus the `csv` module is written in C).

For example:

```
import csv


file_location = 'abc.tsv'
output_filename = 'sample.tsv'
infields =  'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'H'
outfields = 'D', 'G', 'A', 'H', 'C', 'B'


def main():
    with open(file_location, 'r', newline='') as inp, \
         open(output_filename, 'w', newline='') as outp:

        reader = csv.DictReader(inp, fieldnames=infields, delimiter='\t')
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outp, fieldnames=outfields, delimiter='\t',
                                extrasaction='ignore')

        writer.writerows(reader)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked like a charm. To make the code little simpler can we write a for loop to read all the headers of the file instead of mentioning all the headers in 'infields' variable?

Comment: RedDragon: You can create the `infields` sequence any way you wish as long as it's before calling `csv.DictReader()` — but you will likely still have to list them out when defining `outfields` (unless that can be defined programmatically in terms of `infields` in some way). Note that the first line could be read manually using `first_line = next(inp)` _before_ the call.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with ease using pandas, just convert the file to a pandas dataframe and alter the columns order as you want of the dataframe and then write it back to a TSV file.

For reading the file into a pandas dataframe use:

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.read_csv("abc.tsv", sep='\t', header=0)
```

You learn about basics of pandas in [here](https://medium.com/dunder-data/minimally-sufficient-pandas-a8e67f2a2428)

Comment: Yes, I know about pandas but I want it in plain old python without the pandas.

Comment: If you want it to be done without pandas one approach you could try is reading each row and converting it to a list as you did, after than you could call a function on the list that would just alter the data on the list in the order that you want your colums to be in, same can be done for each row and then store the rows in your result (sample.tsv)

Comment: Yes, Exactly ! But I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

(I did not change the table headers locations)
I have also skipped reading/writing  from/to files since I assume this is not a challenge for you.

```
original_data = [['A','B','C'],['a1','b1','c1'],['a2','b2','c2']]

def switch_columns(column_pairs,entries):
  for pair in column_pairs:
    for idx,entry in enumerate(entries):
      if idx > 0: 
        temp = entry[pair[0]]
        entry[pair[0]] = entry[pair[1]]
        entry[pair[1]] = temp

print('Before:')
print(original_data)
switch_columns([(0,2)],original_data)
print('After:')
print(original_data)
```

output

```
Before:
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2']]
After:
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['c1', 'b1', 'a1'], ['c2', 'b2', 'a2']]
```